# Functions in Set Theory-Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ with $A_1,A_2 \subset X$ and $B_1, B_2 \subset Y$ Show that: $f^{-1} (Y-B_1)=X-f^{-1}(B_1)$. I keep  getting jumbled when I attempt this one. and can't seem to get a grasp on it. Thank you!

Comment: is the set $B_2$ used in any place?

Comment: What do you mean in any place?

Comment: It seems that $A_1,A_2$ and $B_2$ are defined but not used in this question. Is this intentional?

Comment: There are other parts to the problem where A1, A2 and B2 are used.

Comment: This is all the information given. I don't know if it is a bijection or not.

Comment: But why did you include them in the question when they are not relevant?

Comment: I just wanted to give the question the way it was given.

Comment: If you plug in the definitions you'll see that the question asks you to show that if $x\in X$, then $f(x)\in Y-B_1$ iff $f(x)\notin B_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let $x \in f^{-1}(Y-B_1)$ then by definition $f(x) \in Y-B_1$, so $f(x) \in Y$ and $f(x) \notin B_1$. It follows that $x \in X$ and, because  $f$ is function and $f(x) \notin B_1$, $x \notin f^{-1}(B_1)$, then $x \in X - f^{-1}(B_1)$. Therefore $f^{-1}(Y-B_1) \subseteq X - f^{-1}(B_1)$.

Now let $y \in X - f^{-1}(B_1)$ then $y \in X$ but $y \notin f^{-1}(B_1)$, so $f(y) \notin B_1$. But $f(y) \in Y$, then $f(y) \in Y - B_1$. It follows that $y \in f^{-1}(Y-B_1)$. Therefore $ X - f^{-1}(B_1) \subseteq  f^{-1}(Y-B_1) $.

Because $f^{-1}(Y-B_1) \subseteq X - f^{-1}(B_1)$ and $ X - f^{-1}(B_1) \subseteq  f^{-1}(Y-B_1) $, we conclude that $X - f^{-1}(B_1) = f^{-1}(Y-B_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to get through this without getting jumbled, then.

In the below, $x$ is taken to be a member of $X$, the domain of $f$.

Consider the statement $x\in f^{-1}(Y-B_1)$.  This is equivalent to the statement $f(x)\in Y-B_1$, which is equivalent to the statement that $f(x)\notin B_1$, which is equivalent to the statement that $x\notin f^{-1}(B_1)$, which is equivalent to the statement that $x\in X-f^{-1}(B_1)$.

Thus, we conclude $x\in f^{-1} (Y-B_1)$ if and only if $x\in X-f^{-1}(B_1)$.

Thus, $f^{-1} (Y-B_1)=X-f^{-1}(B_1)$